# How to add external Excel file in Scala Jar in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark-mllib

I want to keep one excel file with my code. If i pass my jar to some other person. He will be able to read excel too.. 
Is there any way to do that in Scala Intellij.

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGQRj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What files are included in JAR depends on the build process that you are following irrespective of IDE being used.

If you are using **sbt** or **maven** then just add the file in `resources` directory and it will be available inside the jar.

Comment: i am adding excel file in resource directory... will it work for that??

Comment: Actually new to this scala/Java. Can u please tell that how to add that step by step. or any link which show how to do that..

Comment: what is your project directory structure?

Comment: add the files in **src/main/resources**